# Searchability of a field

Tags: search, global-search

I have a text field in the account object and it has the searchable option ticked. But yet when I search using the global search it is not visible. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to search any field please check whether it is added in Search Layout of that particular Object. Also refer this article [Explore your searchable fields by object in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_fields_lex.htm&type=5)

this article will help you to find  which records you can find with Salesforce search